# JavaScript OOP function reference not yet declared

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I'm here yet again to solve another Javascript enigma.

Consider this code:

```js
starmap = function(game){

    this.PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    this.renderer = {
      ...
    }
    
    this.star = function (...) {
      console.log(this.map);
      ...
    }
      
    this.map = {
      ...
    }
}
    
starmap.prototype = {

    preload: function(){},
    create : function(){
        this.map.initialize('starmap');
    },

    update: function(){
        
    }
}
```

The map.initialize calls star and star inside itself has references to map, but I'm getting the error of it not being defined when I started.

for now I've solved it by adding

```
var m = this.map
```

right under the map declaration, but this seems a bit wacky.
**What is the correct way of doing this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Show the `map.initialize` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the "this" to a regular variable:

```
starmap = function(game){

    var self = this; //<----

    self.PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
```

and then replace all the uses of `this` with `self`. For example, `self.map` instead of `this.map`. Using `this` in Javascript is tricky because its value changes depending on how you called the current function.

Comment: ah! Such a brilliant solution, so simple!
I did not think about that!

Comment: its a very common JS hack. Usually people name the variable "self" or "that"